# How to append a column for the result set in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a script for the below scenario.  I am very new to shell script.

```
wc file1 file2
```

the above query results with following result

```
40     149     947   file1
2294   16638   97724 file2
```

Now I need to get result as follows: 1st column, 3rd column ,4th column of above result set and new column with default values

```
40    947   file1  DF.tx1
2294  97724 file2  DF.rb2
```

Here the last column values is always known values i.e for file1 DF.tx1 and file2 DF.rb2.

If the give filenames in any order the default values should not change.

Please help me to write this script. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is there a separate input that shows the "known values"? If so, you should [edit] your question to show us the lines we need in your example in the right format. If not, how are they known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
wc file1 file2 | 
  awk '$4 != "total"{if ($4 ~ /file1/) f="DF.tx1"; else if ($4 ~ /file2/) f="DF.rb2";
         else if ($4 ~ /file3/) f="foo.bar"; print $1, $3, $4, f}'

1 12 file1 DF.tx1
9 105 file2 DF.rb2
5 15 file3 foo.bar
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response anubhava. Here if the file name is file1 then its df.tx1 else sf.rb2 will be resulted. if  I have more than 2 files then how to get default values for the same????